# 18 hrs layover at Narita International airport

Tags: transit, indian-citizens, transit-visas, japan, nrt

I have Indian passport and currently visiting USA with my wife.  While returning to India in January 2020, we have 18 hrs layover at Narita International (NRT). From USA we will be travelling by American Airlines and from Japan by Japan airlines.
Do we need transit visa for 18 hrs to stay in a hotel at NRT airport.
What is shore pass?

Comment: @Michael Hampton Out of interest I ran the OP’s journey details through Timatic and no mention of a shore pass came up?

Comment: @Traveller Try again? It's there as of ten seconds ago.

Comment: @Michael Hampton Nope, still not seeing it https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external-result/oVg8HXeQxDggZ14c_0T4gUzYR9ig I must be entering something incorrectly. Thought it was worth checking with you, however.

Comment: @Traveller I don't know what site you got there from or what you entered, but the entire TWOV section is missing. Maybe that's just because a transit visa is not required, but it's hard to be sure. And I don't like that "passenger simplified" result page either. That's not anything like what the airlines see. Try [another interface](https://cms.olympicair.com/timatic/webdocsI/spdbmainv.html).